# What is a "classically chaotic quantum system"?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, terminology, definition, chaos-theory

In the context of [quantum mirages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_mirage) one can find increased *probability density around paths of unstable classical periodic orbits*, called [quantum scarring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_mirage). In this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_scar) they use the term "classically chaotic quantum system". What is such a system precisely?

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of quantum chaos, one is quantum single-body chaos while the other is quantum many-body chaos. The difference is what's the number of degrees of freedom in the system.

For example, eigenmode for some billiard systems like [deformed Whispering-gallery mode](https://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.87.61) exhibit chaotic behavior, but the number of DOF is only 2. On the other hand, a chaotic quantum spin chain involves $N$ degrees of freedom which manifest the many-body nature.

The so-called classically chaotic quantum system usually refers to a quantum system whose Hamiltonian (or equation of motion) has a very obvious classical counterpart and exhibits chaos. Such as the deformed WGM I mentioned earlier. The scar modes of WGM cavities are studied thoroughly during the past decades.

The quantum spin chain (for spin-1/2), on the other hand, does not have a very clear classical counterpart because the quantum fluctuation is dominating the dynamics. For these kinds of systems, however, some symmetry or emerged trajectories have mean-field (classical) dynamics. These special trajectories are called quantum many-body scars.